# How to determine if a string is a protocol buffer object or not

Tags: protocol-buffers

I have a location that stores plain string data right now and I want to store at the same location a protobuf object in the future.

Is there a way for my new code to read the old data (plain string) and reliably determine: "this is not a protobuf object"?

Given that I can't reliably determine the format of the current plain string data (e.g. hostnames) from other formats (it's possible that some protocol buffer objects resemble hostnames, which could be anything) either, it doesn't seem feasible right?

Comment: Are the strings ascii text?  Protobufs are stored as binary gibberish, so you should be able to tell fairly easily if the bits at a given location are ascii or not.

Comment: Unfortunately the strings are not ascii. Part of it is just a C++ std::string which could be anything. Full definition: https://github.com/apache/mesos/blob/master/3rdparty/libprocess/include/process/pid.hpp

Comment: You can do this "with some confidence" by running the data through a protobuf parser to see if it errors, but: there is always a theoretical chance of something looking like protobuf *by chance* - especially for small sequences (the chances of coincidence falling with length). Also, a zero-length string is completely valid in protobuf, and presumably a few other things.

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah I guess the theoretical chance is what I was worrying about here. I guess I can't be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't yet stored any protocol buffers data in the location. How about marking the new data with some specific prefix?

For example, generate a GUID or just some random 64-bit value, and prepend it to the data whenever you store a protobuf message. On reading, just check if this marker is present.

By varying the length of the marker, you can make any collisions with existing data arbitrarily improbable.